# Changing webview settings on android for Ionic application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-webview, pouchdb

I am using pouchdb on my Ionic application and currently dealing with [DOMException code:18](http://pouchdb.com/errors.html#android_pre_kitkat) error.
The documentation asks me to change the settings for android.

**EDIT**
I found that I have to make these changes in MainActivity.java
This is the code i wrote.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    WebView webView = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        String databasePath = getContext().getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
        settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          @Override
          public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize,
                                              long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2);
          }
        });
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

When i compile this I get error - R.id.webView -> It seems my resource name is incorrect , it cannot find webView in resources. I searched the platforms/android folder but I cannot locate the layout file.
Also, I am not using eclipse, I use atom editor for ionic project.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because you don't have the webview defined on a layout file.

But you can do it like this:

```
    SystemWebView webView = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView  = (SystemWebView) appView.getView();
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        String databasePath = appView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
        settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize,
                                                long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
                quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2);
            }
        });
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
```